# Is there an efficient way to find all ordered arrangements of elements in the set S that add up to N?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, optimization

Here's what I mean. Suppose `S = {1, 4}` and `N = 5`. The ordered arrangements of elements in the set `S` would be like

`{1}, {4}, {1,1}, {1,4}, {4,1}, {4,4}, {1,1,1}, ....`

and the ones that sum up to `N` are

`{1,4}, {4, 1}, {1,1,1,1,1}`

I want an algorithm that finds those efficiently.

My "brute force" way would be like

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> OrderedArrangements(IEnumerable<int> nums, int k)
{
    var singles = nums.Select(i => new int[] {i} );
    var cumulative = singles;
    for(int j = 2; j <= k; ++j)
    {
        var last = cumulative.Where(list => list.Count() == (j - 1));
        var next = from x in singles
                   from y in last
                   select x.Concat(y);
        cumulative = cumulative.Concat(next);           
    }
    return cumulative;
}
```

and then

```
int sumToN = OrderedArrangements(new int[] {1, 4}, N)
                .Where(x => x.Sum() == N);
```

but I'm wondering if there's an obvious and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Note that in the general case, if you allow elements to be used more than once, your result may be infinitely large if your input contains zero or negative numbers.

Comment: @hvd There are no zero or negative numbers, I should add

Comment: Would it be more efficient to start from `N` and successively subtract each element of `S`, and record all paths that end up with 0? Also, you're treatng `{1,4}` and `{4,1}` as distinct cases, where for the purposes of the calculation they are the same. Afterwards you can expand one to the other.

Comment: You're asking for all "ordered arrangements" and then saying that `{ 4, 1 }` is in the set of solutions, but that's not in order. What do you mean by "ordered"?

Comment: @Enigmativity it appears that what is being asked for here is the set of all tuples containing only elements from S that meet the specified condition. The "ordered arrangement" should probably be more clearly called a tuple. That appears to be emphasising that sets (which have no order) that meet the specified condition are not what is wanted. Terminology could definitely be modified for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case the above answer isn't clear enough, you could try straight forward recursion e.g.

```
     ...
    /       \
   (1)     (4)          
  /  \     /  \
 (1)(4)   (1)(4)
```

```java
static void f(int sum, int n, String str, int[] arr){
    if (n == sum){
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        return;
    }
    if (n > sum) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++){
        f(sum, n + arr[i], str + arr[i].ToString(), arr);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args){
    int[] arr =  { 1, 4 };
    f(5, 0, "", arr);
}
```

Where `sum` is `N` in your question, `n` is initialized to `0`, `str` is initialized to `""` and `arr` is `S` in your question.

output:

```
11111
14
41
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> OrderedArrangements(IEnumerable<int> nums, int k)
{
    return
        k <= 0
            ? new [] { Enumerable.Empty<int>() }
            : nums
                .SelectMany(
                    n => OrderedArrangements(nums, k - n),
                    (n, ns) => new [] { n }.Concat(ns))
                .Where(ns => ns.Sum() == k);
}
```

The result of `OrderedArrangements(new [] { 1, 4 }, 5)` is:

[image: result]

---

I ran this performance testing code:

```
Func<Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>>, double> measure = f =>
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = f();
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
};

var n = 200;
var a = 0.0;
var b = 0.0;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a += measure(() => OrderedArrangements_A(new [] { 1, 4, 9, 13 }, 50000));
    b += measure(() => OrderedArrangements_B(new [] { 1, 4, 9, 13 }, 50000));
}
```

`OrderedArrangements_A` is the OP's code and `OrderedArrangements_B` is mine.

I got an average of 15.6ms for "A" and 0.004ms for "B". My code run about 3,895 times faster for this test.

Comment: Can you explain why your solution is more efficient than the brute force solution proposed by OP? It seems like OP has a *working* solution already. This one is certainly more elegant. but is it faster? (I'm not saying that it isn't; just that I think a good answer would address the question.)

Comment: Having said that, it is quite likely that this q&a fits better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @rici - I've added to the answer.

Comment: @rici - It doesn't appear that the OP's solution works so I don't think it is worth comparing as to why there's a difference.